Post-Processing Maze to Eulerian Issues in 2D DFS Maze Generator
I am working on a C# program that generates a maze using a DFS algorithm. The maze generation works correctly, but I'm struggling with the post-processing methods to turn the generated maze into an Eulerian maze. Despite several attempts, the maze does not become Eulerian as expected.
My approach:

Generate the maze using DFS.

Identify vertices with odd degrees.

Attempt to connect pairs of vertices with odd degrees to make the maze Eulerian.

GenerateLevel(): Generates the initial maze.

GetOddDegree(): Identifies vertices with odd degrees.

ConnectVertices(): Connects vertices to balance their degrees.

MakeMazeEulerian(): Main method to post-process the maze to make it Eulerian.


My code
Current Output
Labyrinthe généré avec l'algorithme de parcours en profondeur :
 █       █         █   █     █
 █ █ █ ███ █████ █ █ █ █████ █
 █ █ █ █   █   █ █ █ █       █
 █ █ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███████ █
 █ █     █     █ █   █   █   █
 █ ███████████ █ ███████ █ ███
   █   █       █ █    E  █ █ █
 ███ █ █ █ █████ █████ █ █ █ █
 █   █   █ █   █     █ █ █ █ █
 █ █████ ███ █ █ ███ █ ███ █ █
   █   █ █   █ █   █ █   █   █
████ ███ █ ███ █████ █ █ ███ █
     █   █ █         █ █ █   █
 █ ███ ███ ███████████ █ █ ███
 █       █  S█         █     █

Labyrinthe rendu Eulerien :
 █       █         █   █     █
 █ █ █ ███ ███ █ █ █ █ █ ███ █
 █ █ █ █   █   █ █ █ █       █
 █ █ ███ ███ ███ █ █ ███████ █
 █ █     █     █ █   █   █   █
 █ ███████████ █ █████ █ █ ███
   █   █       █ █       █ █ █
 ███ █ █ █ █████ █ ███ █ █ █ █
 █   █     █         █   █ █ █
 █ █████ ███ █ █ █ █ █ ███ █ █
   █   █ █   █           █   █
████ █ █ █ █ █ █████ █ █ ███ █
     █   █ █         █ █ █   █
 █ ███ █ █ █ █ ███████ █ █ ███
 █       █  S█         █     █

Degrés des sommets avant et après rendu Eulerien :
1 0 2 2 3 2 3 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 0   1 0 2 2 3 2 3 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0
2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0   2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0
2 0 2 0 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 0   2 0 2 0 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 0
2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0   2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 2 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 0 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 0   2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 2 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 0
2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0   2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0
3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 0 2 0 1 0   3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 4 2 3 0 2 0 1 0
2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0   2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0
2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 0 1 0 2 2 2 0 3 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 0   2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 3 2 4 2 4 2 2 0 3 2 2 0 2 0 2 0
2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0   2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0
2 2 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 1 0 2 0 3 2 2 0 2 2 3 0   2 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 3 0 3 2 3 2 3 2 4 2 4 2 2 0 2 2 3 0 
0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0   0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0
2 2 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 0   2 2 3 2 2 0 3 2 3 0 2 0 3 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 0
2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0   2 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0
1 0 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 0 2 2 1 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 2 1 0   1 0 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 3 2 1 0

My problem is that after running MakeMazeEulerian(), the maze still does not satisfy Eulerian properties. a few constraints I must adhere to:

The maze must be post-processed to become Eulerian.
The maze must be represented by a 2D array.
I must use a DFS algorithm to initially generate the maze.

public class MazeGenerator
{
    public int _width;
    public int _height;
    public Cell[,] _map;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public MazeGenerator(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _map = new Cell[_width, _height];
    }
    private List<CellCoordinates> GetUnvisitedNeighbors(CellCoordinates cell)
    {
        List<CellCoordinates> neighbors = new List<CellCoordinates>();

        (int, int)[] directions = { (0, 2), (0, -2), (2, 0), (-2, 0) };

        foreach (var direction in directions)
        {
            CellCoordinates neighbor = new CellCoordinates(cell.X + direction.Item1, cell.Y + direction.Item2);

            if (IsInBounds(neighbor) && _map[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y] == Cell.Wall)
                neighbors.Add(neighbor);
        }

        return neighbors;
    }


    private bool IsInBounds(CellCoordinates cell)
    {
        return cell.X >= 0 && cell.X < _width && cell.Y >= 0 && cell.Y < _height;
    }

    private void RemoveWallBetween(CellCoordinates a, CellCoordinates b)
    {
        CellCoordinates wall = new CellCoordinates((a.X + b.X) / 2, (a.Y + b.Y) / 2);
        _map[wall.X, wall.Y] = Cell.Empty;
    }

    private void GenerateDFSMazeIterative(CellCoordinates start)
    {
        Stack<CellCoordinates> stack = new Stack<CellCoordinates>();
        stack.Push(start);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            CellCoordinates current = stack.Pop();

            var neighbors = GetUnvisitedNeighbors(current);

            if (neighbors.Count > 0)
            {
                stack.Push(current);

                CellCoordinates next = neighbors[random.Next(neighbors.Count)];

                RemoveWallBetween(current, next);

                _map[next.X, next.Y] = Cell.Empty;

                stack.Push(next);
            }
        }
    }
    public void GenerateLevel()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
                _map[x, y] = Cell.Wall;

        CellCoordinates start, end;
        do
        {
            start = new CellCoordinates(random.Next(0, _width), random.Next(0, _height));
            end = new CellCoordinates(random.Next(0, _width), random.Next(0, _height));
        } while (start.X == end.X && start.Y == end.Y);

        _map[start.X, start.Y] = Cell.Start;

        GenerateDFSMazeIterative(start);

        while (_map[end.X, end.Y] != Cell.Empty)
            end = new CellCoordinates(random.Next(0, _width), random.Next(0, _height));

        _map[end.X, end.Y] = Cell.End;
    }

    private IEnumerable<CellCoordinates> GetNeighbors(CellCoordinates cell)
    {
        (int, int)[] directions = { (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0) };
        foreach (var direction in directions)
        {
            CellCoordinates neighbor = new CellCoordinates(cell.X + direction.Item1, cell.Y + direction.Item2);
            if (IsInBounds(neighbor) && _map[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y] != Cell.Wall)
                yield return neighbor;
        }
    }

    private int BFS(CellCoordinates start, CellCoordinates end)
    {
        if (start.Equals(end)) return 0; // No distance if start and end are the same

        var queue = new Queue<CellCoordinates>();
        var visited = new HashSet<CellCoordinates>();
        var distances = new Dictionary<CellCoordinates, int>();

        // Initialize BFS
        queue.Enqueue(start);
        visited.Add(start);
        distances[start] = 0; // Start point has distance 0

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = queue.Dequeue();

            foreach (var neighbor in GetNeighbors(current))
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(neighbor))
                {
                    visited.Add(neighbor);
                    queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
                    distances[neighbor] = distances[current] + 1;

                    if (neighbor.Equals(end))
                    {
                        return distances[neighbor];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private List<CellCoordinates> GetOddDegree()
    {
        var oddDegreeVertices = new List<CellCoordinates>();
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
            {
                if (_map[x, y] == Cell.Empty || _map[x, y] == Cell.End || _map[x, y] == Cell.Start)
                {
                    var degree = GetDegree(new CellCoordinates(x, y));
                    if (degree % 2 != 0)
                        oddDegreeVertices.Add(new CellCoordinates(x, y));
                }
            }
        }
        return oddDegreeVertices;
    }

    private int GetDegree(CellCoordinates vertex)
    {
        int degree = 0;
        (int, int)[] directions = { (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0) };

        foreach (var direction in directions)
        {
            CellCoordinates neighbor = new CellCoordinates(vertex.X + direction.Item1, vertex.Y + direction.Item2);
            if (IsInBounds(neighbor) && _map[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y] != Cell.Wall)
                degree++;
        }

        return degree;
    }

    private IEnumerable<CellCoordinates> GetPotentialPathPoints(CellCoordinates cell)
    {
        (int, int)[] directions = { (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0) };
        foreach (var direction in directions)
        {
            CellCoordinates potentialPathPoint = new CellCoordinates(cell.X + direction.Item1, cell.Y + direction.Item2);
            if (IsInBounds(potentialPathPoint))
                yield return potentialPathPoint;  // Consider all in-bounds cells
        }
    }

    private void RestorePath(Dictionary<CellCoordinates, CellCoordinates?> cameFrom, CellCoordinates end)
    {
        CellCoordinates current = end;
        while (cameFrom[current] != null)
        {
            var previous = cameFrom[current].Value;
            RemoveWallBetween(current, previous);
            current = previous;
        }
    }

    private void ConnectVertices(CellCoordinates start, CellCoordinates end)
    {
        Queue<CellCoordinates> queue = new Queue<CellCoordinates>();
        Dictionary<CellCoordinates, CellCoordinates?> cameFrom = new Dictionary<CellCoordinates, CellCoordinates?>();
        queue.Enqueue(start);
        cameFrom[start] = null;

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = queue.Dequeue();

            if (current.Equals(end))
            {
                RestorePath(cameFrom, current);
                return;
            }
            foreach (var neighbor in GetPotentialPathPoints(current))
            {
                if (!cameFrom.ContainsKey(neighbor))
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
                    cameFrom[neighbor] = current;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MakeMazeEulerian()
    {
        List<CellCoordinates> oddVertices = GetOddDegree();
        while (oddVertices.Count > 0)
        {
            CellCoordinates v1 = oddVertices[0];
            oddVertices.RemoveAt(0);

            CellCoordinates? closestOddVertex = null;
            int minDistance = int.MaxValue;

            foreach (var v2 in oddVertices)
            {
                int distance = BFS(v1, v2);
                if (distance < minDistance)
                {
                    minDistance = distance;
                    closestOddVertex = v2;
                }
            }

            if (closestOddVertex.HasValue)
            {
                ConnectVertices(v1, closestOddVertex.Value);
                oddVertices.Remove(closestOddVertex.Value);
            }
        }
    }

Thank you for your help.
Defintion of Eulerian Maze in my context

Starts at a specified cell.
Travels through every passage in the maze exactly once.
Returns to the starting cell without retracing any path.


Link to my code

You need to read up (in the [help]) on how to write a good question. In particular you should include a [mre] as text (formatted as code), not as a link to somewhere

i wanted to add some code, but apparently, my code is long, the verison of the gist is already a minimal vrsion of my code, i will try to upload the code in several pieces

You should probably define "eulerian maze", none of the top google hits produce a clear definition.
